# How To Insert Custom Values Into Existing Plist Array Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I am trying to Insert some additional data's into my `propertylist` array data's.

My Actual Scenario Below:

I am getting some `JSON` data from server and directly load Into `plist`. Into this plist I have to add some custom keys and values with type.
I need to add `isChild` and `level` values inside subject array items. Please check Image below I have `red marked`, what I want to achieve.

My JSON Response:

```
{ 
   "response":{ 
      "A":{ 
         "name":"Arun",
         "age":"20",
         "city":"SFO",
         "subject":[{
            "place":SFO
        }]
      },
      "B":{ 
         "name":"Benny",
         "age":"20",
         "city":"SFO",
         "subject":[{
            "place":SFO
            },
            {
            "place":ADS
        }]
    },
      "C":{ 
         "name":"Nani",
         "age":"30",
         "city":"SFO",
      }
   },
   "inprogressdata":{ 
   },
   "dataspeed":"112 m..."
}
```

My Plist :

[image]

My Code :

```
NSError *error;
        NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves | NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
        NSDictionary *response = JSON[@"response"];
        NSArray *keys = [response allKeys];
        NSMutableArray *objects = [NSMutableArray new];

        for (NSString *key in keys) {
            NSMutableDictionary *object = response[key];
            [object setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"level"];
            [object setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"isParent"]; // Here I am adding isParent easily
            [objects addObject:object];

            //NSLog(@"SIGNALEVENT :%@",[object valueForKey:@"subject"]);
            //Here I need to add isChild Boolean and level values under the subject within subject Items like above Image
        }
```

`MY Issue :` Need to add `isChild` and `level` kyes and values under the subject within all items, like above Image!

Comment: I need to add isChild and level keys like above mentioed image!@PravinTate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (NSString *key in keys) {
        NSMutableDictionary *object = response[key];
        NSMutableArray * subjectArray = object[@"subject"];
        for (NSMutableDictionary * dict in subjectArray) {
            [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:true] forKey:@"isChild"];
            [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"level"];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please update my code. It will give more clarity bro!

Comment: @Sanju use my code in your for loop check it working on not for you first. there is no any sense to update your code

Comment: now it will add these two keys in add subject indexes as per your requirement, update answer

Comment: Awesome brother. Great help!@ Pravin Tate

Comment: thanks! If it helps you up vote it, so other will take it as reference. and if you need any type of help of regarding iOS just mail me on tate.pravin@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you. Btw Upvote I dont have much reputation.Once I reached 15 I will do It! Thank you So much!@Pravin Tate